# Symmetric and Asymmetric in Aspect Oriented Programming

Tags: architecture, aop, aspect

I've heard about Symmetric and Asymmetric in Aspect Oriented Programming, but I don't understand what they are. In fact, from a paper, it said:

> Symmetric: All concerns are modularized with the same kind of module
>   Asymmetric: Different module kind for crosscutting concerns

Could you please explain in more details, and give me an example?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Asymmetric aspects** means that you have 2 seperate modules;

- your base program
- aspects (where aspects are abstracted pieces of code that can be used in multiple places of your program, to avoid code duplication or scattering and tangling or dependencies between systems | *also called crosscutting concerns*)

and you weave them together before you compile (at pre-compile time) to make your program.

**Symmetric aspects** means that your concerns are abstracted in the base program modules themselves. (which can also be woven together to make your program)

Comment: Thanks for your easy-to-understand answer!